# Repeated letters logic not working in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am working on a version of hangman, and I need to include a condition that checks if a letter guess was already used. My repeated letters if statement is not working correctly. Any advice?

***NOT FULL CODE. ONLY A PIECE IS SHOWN***

```
    char[] repeatedLetters = new char[26];

    int incorrect = 0;
    while (incorrect < 7)
    {
        System.out.println("\nGuess a letter: ");
        char guess = kb.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);  // case insensitive

        for (int i = 0; i < repeatedLetters.length; i++)
        {
            if (repeatedLetters[i] == guess) {
                System.out.println("You already guessed " + guess + ".");
                System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");
                guess = kb.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            }
            else 
                repeatedLetters[i] = guess;     
        }
```

Comment: Your code is pretty far from working, but I will say that the data structure you might want to use for repeated letters would be a hash map, which maps letters to a boolean value (true if duplicate, false if available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest using a `List` instead of array.

```
List<Character> repeatedLetters = new ArrayList<>();

int incorrect = 0;
while (incorrect < 7)
{
    System.out.println("\nGuess a letter: ");
    char guess = kb.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);  // case insensitive

    if (validateCharacter(guess) && repeatedLetters.contains(guess)) {
        System.out.println("You already guessed " + guess + ".");
        continue;
    }
    else {
        repeatedLetters.add(guess);
    }

    // Other things
}
```

If you are not allowed to use a list, then you need to move the `else` block outside of the `for` loop, use a labelled `while` loop, and also manually count the number of repeated characters.

```
int repeatedCount = 0;
getInput : while (incorrect < 7) {
    // ......
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatedCount; i++) {
        if (repeatedLetters[i] == guess) {
            System.out.println("You already guessed " + guess + ".");
            continue getInput;
        }
    }
    repeatedLetters[repeatedCount] = guess; 
    repeatedCount++;
```